# How to solve foreign key constraints fails error when manually inserting the child table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am using MySQLi to connect to my database and my problem is that I want to insert in the database but I get this error:

> Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`edi_tracker_revised`.`edi_transaction`, CONSTRAINT
>   `edi_transaction_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`edi_doc_type_id`) REFERENCES
>   `edi_doc_type` (`edi_doc_type_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE
>   CASCADE)

Here is my code for insert.

```
 if ($doc_type == '812') {

            $edi_doc_type_id = "SELECT edi_doc_type_id FROM `edi_doc_type` WHERE doc_type = 812 " ;

            $sql = "INSERT INTO edi_transaction (`sender_id`,`receiver_id`,`isa_number`,`transaction_date`,`gs_number`,`edi_doc_type_id`,`ref_number`,`file_name`,`file_path`,`creation_date`) 
                        VALUES ('$sender_id','$receiver_id','$isa_number','$transaction_date','$gs_number','$edi_doc_type_id','$ref_number','$file_name','$file_path',NOW()) " ;
                $ref_numberArray = explode(',' ,$ref_number); // the ref_number contains the invoice numbers


                //Checking query if it is successful
                if ($conn->query($sql) === false){
                    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . 'Error: ' . $conn->error , E_USER_ERROR);
                }else {
                    echo "Successful ! Data is inserted in database ^__^" ;

                }
        }
```

When I say manually, I insert with the use of phpmyadmin , and now how can I fix it if I populate first my edi_doc_type manually before edi_transaction? I need the edi_doc_type_id in my edi_transaction table. Can somebody help me?

Comment: The whole point of a foreign key constraint is to not insert stuff in the table that's constrained by a key. Depending on what relations you have between your tables you should never have to do what you did.

Comment: but I thought it is one way so ,there will be no redundancy in my data , I thought that if I insert using code there is a tendency that I will have a redundant data... so what should i do? can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

`` $edi_doc_type_id = "SELECT edi_doc_type_id FROM `edi_doc_type` WHERE doc_type = 812 " ; `` isn't executing the query, it's just a string assignment. Since `` SELECT edi_doc_type_id FROM `edi_doc_type` WHERE doc_type = 812 `` isn't a valid ID, the second query is failing.

You should execute the SELECT query and read out the edi_doc_type_id before using it in the second query.

It would also be worth looking into prepared statements or escaping the values to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: can you give example on how can I do it?

Comment: Use [mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to execute the SELECT query and return a mysqli_stmt object. Then use [mysqli_stmt::bind_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) and [mysqli_stmt::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) to fetch the ID.

You can read more about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in the PHP manual too.

Answer (score 0):

What is the benefit of foreign keys even you are trying to bypass them-

Further if you want it then you can use as per below-

```
set foreign_key_checks=0;
insert....
set foreign_key_checks=1;
```

But this is not good practice.

Comment: execute just like a statment as i have updated. your insert statment will be between these 2 statements.